# ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, sentestingkit

So I'm having a bit of an issue, Apple has rejected my app for the past 3 times. And they've always left me with this error.

```
Incident Identifier: 0F8AC4C8-57A6-4E1E-BE2B-0A93E6A85564
CrashReporter Key:   03e6d04a9f8fcf7989c751d0befe3b50ff6720c8
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Unoffical Statitics [1012]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/0A0DD25F-0320-4D79-BB3D-F69A9823B82C/Unoffical Statitics.app/Unoffical Statitics
Identifier:          com.APPSTARME.ManUtd
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-02-12 10:44:08.759 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/0A0DD25F-0320-4D79-BB3D-F69A9823B82C/Unoffical Statitics.app/Unoffical Statitics
  Reason: image not found
  Dyld Version: 324

Binary Images:
0x2befd000 - 0x2bf1d77a dyld armv7s  <fd7cb81f388f39cbac4f71338b669c24> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3ae07000 - 0x3aebafff libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <810acee8bebe317492118d752643bde3> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
```

so I've been trying to solve this issue with no luck at all, however I just removed all of my Framework Search Path (Xcode sets this one now as default `$(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR)`)

However when I try to run the app now I'm receiving this error

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode51-DP2.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

run this command on your client.app:

export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xct‌oolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH

in terms of the name of your Xcode is Xocde.app.